# Why mention the number of words in parshat mieketz

Tags: number, mesorah-tradition, miketz

Why does Parshat Miketz conclude by specifying the total number of words in the parsha, whereas other parshas typically only indicate the number of pesukim?

Answer (score 3):

In [**ספר פני החמה by R. Moshe Gelbein** (*Kiryat Sefer, 5774*)](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/600199/p/1/t/1702795758061/fs/0/start/0/end/0/c), on pp. 53-54 this question is addressed - see the following image for the original wording (*for those who don't have access to Otzar HaChochma*).

[image]

**Summary of the three answers quoted:**

1. In **פנינים משלחן הגר"א**, it says that the **Gr"a** held that the *baalei hamesora* were careful to note that **פוטי-פרע** is **counted as two words** and only a count of 2,025 words will align with that.
2. The **בני יששכר** writes in the name of the author of the **עטרת צבי from Ziditchov** that Mikeitz normally falls out on Chanuka as a hint to Chanuka which starts on the **25th of the month** and we light for **eight nights**: 2,025 = 25 + (8 x 250), where 250 is equivalent to **the *gematria* of נר**.
3. In **ספר תפוחי חיים** it's written that the *baalei hamesora* were careful to note that **אברך** is **counted as one word** (*to eliminate the thought that it might be written as 2 words according to the drasha Rashi brings from the Sifri*) and only a count of 2,025 words will align with that (*in a similar vein to the Gr"a, but focusing on a different word*).

**A side note**: *if one carefully counts the words in our Chumashim and Sifrei Torah, **[a word count of only 2,022](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTS7WQpca-NJviiOl71QfSXb-_gl3S__7qiApm1-uwckqUqFzfn7SdvXImrEr5K1HeQKRGTBr4lb5Tu/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true)** will emerge for פרשת מקץ even if counting פוטי-פרע as two words.*

**Additionally**: In the [1525 edition of the Mikraos Gedolos](https://archive.org/details/mikraot_gdolot/Torah/) published by Daniel Bomberg with the assistance of [Yaakov ben Chaim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95) there are actually **six parshios haShavua** that contain a word count at the end in addition to simanim for pasuk counts.

[image]

Below I list them with their **counts** as listed in that Mikraos Gedolos (*counts based on total words appearing in most current Chumashim/Sifrei Torah are in parentheses*)

These are:

- Mikeitz: **2,025** (*2,022 as mentioned above*)
- Korach: **1,462** (*1,409*)
- Chukas: **1,454** (*1,245*)
- Balak: **1,450** (*1,455*)
- VaEschanan: **1,870** (*1,878*)
- Eikev: **1,746** (*1,747*)

*(see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138945/33217) as to **why** those discrepancies exist)*

At some later point in time, prints of Mikraos Gedolos only included the count for Mikeitz but did not include the five others.

Comment: Of course, if you combine the concerns of points 1 and 3, you could write פוטיפרע as one word and אב רך as two words, and still end up with a total word count of 2,025.

Comment: Where's the discrepancy ?

Comment: Not sure exactly on which words the 2,025 differs.  I generated a numbered word listing with the 2,022 words in sequence for perusal but that would be a bit long to post here.  I could generate a PDF file with that - I only see a way here to paste images but not to attach files.

Comment: I posted a [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138945/33217)

Comment: You can share a pdf with a link

Comment: I added a link to a Google Sheet above.

Comment: Some chumashim and siftei torah write פוטי פרע as two words and some as one word פוטיפרע

Comment: I have seen in https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/משתמש:Dovi/מקרא_על_פי_המסורה/מידע_על_מהדורה_זו that פוטי פרע is mainly used and Teimani sefarim have פוטיפרע as one word.  Interested to know if there are others. Simanim (based on Leningrad Codex), Koren, Artscroll Mikraos Gedolos and Daas Mikra have as two words.