# Discrepancy of word count in parashat mikets

Tags: miketz

EraserX pointed out in this [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138944/33217), that there is a discrepancy between the word count listed (2 025) and the actual number (2 022) of words in parashat mikets.

Are we missing words ?

Answer (score 4):

Rav Avraham Meisels (of Montreal) writes in his Sefer "מטבע של אברהם" (pg. 172), after mentioning a few reasons given for the letter count appearing at the end of the parsha:

> אולם אני בעניי ספרתי ומניתי התיבות שבפרשה, ובסך הכל הם ב' אלפים כ"ב, ולא כ"ה, והוא פלא, ואפשר ליישבו בדוחק, לפי דברי רש"י בשני מקומות בפ' כ' הרי זה מקרא קצר, ובכללו מכוין, פרע"ה השיב על כני (בפסוק מ"א י"ג) - עד כי חדל ל"ו הסופ"ר לספור (בפסוק מ"א מ"ט), הרי שלשה וצ"ע ליישב המסורה.
>
> However, I, in my poverty counted the letters in the parsha, and they are only 2022, not 2025, and this is a wonder, and it can be settled with difficulty, according to Rashi's comment on two places in the parsha, where he wrote "this is a shortened passuk" in which is included '**Par'o** returned me to my seat' (41:13), and 'until **the counter** stopped counting' (41:49), and this is [the] three [missing words], and it needs stufy to settle.

Basically, the two times Rashi says it's a 'shortened passuk' [ meaning, a passuk missing a subject (and referring only to a previously unidentified pronoun)], he would add in three words altogether (פרעה, לו, הסופר). These three words, claims Rav Avraham Meisels, are the three words that make up the discrepancy. Though he says this all as *dochak* and leaves it in a *tzarich iyun*.

Comment: It is an answer; though, as you note, not a very compelling one.

Comment: I have seen this answer suggested and am investigating whether there are other possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

See new info posted to the [aforementioned answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/138944/33217) showing the 6 parshios in the Mikraos Gedolos of 1525 and the discrepancies with their printed word counts.

I exchanged some emails with Rabbi Yakov Schonberg of Ramat Beit Shemesh who has delved into masoretic issues for many years.

According to what I gleaned from him, this is a complex issue and doesn't have easy solutions (*I hope I have represented his thoughts accurately below*).

While it's possible to attribute the discrepancies to errors in transcribing original *kisvei yad* or printer errors for the smaller discrepancies (*I have considered this myself*), it's not all that simple since why are there instances of very large discrepancies (eg. Korach: 1,462 vs. 1,409 and Chukas: 1,454 vs. 1,245)?

Another complexity can be that if an original *ksav yad* contained a letter-based *siman* to represent an actual number, the very same letters could be misinterpreted as a totally different number (eg. שד as 304 could easily have been retranscribed as דש (to avoid the negative connotation of a שד) and then be misinterpreted as 4,300!). Also, there were multiple methods of encoding numbers with letter-based simanim.

To add to the complications is that while the current Arabic-based system of writing numbers (0..9) includes the concept of zeroes as placeholders, letter-based *simanim* lack that.

Another possibility is that whatever counts were used in the Mikraos Gedolos of 1525 could have altogether been based on a different method for counting words which is currently unknown to us.